# Url Rewrite from one page to another

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL like

```
www.testwebsite.com?param1=abc
or
www.testwebsite.com/?param1=abc
```

I need to redirect to

www.testwebsite.com/level1/xyz.html?customparam=123**&param1=abc**

I tried working on rewrite url but i am still new to this and need some help to achieve the solution

This is what i did till now

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param1=(.+) 
RewriteRule ^/$ /level1/xyz.html?customparam=123&param1=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

Only param1 will be captured and passed through, other query string params will be dropped.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if the param1 parameter is present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(param1=([^&]+))(&|$) [NC] 
#redirect
RewriteRule ^$ level1/xyz.html?customparam=123&%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, but there is one more thing i have to do in this URL

The url can be like this www.testwebsite.com?param1=abc&param2=xyz

I do not need the param2 in the new query string after redirection